# "Reversing" a hook in J

Tags: j

I want to put the operation which takes all the items in a list which are greater than 2 into a pointless (as in not explicitly capturing the argument in a variable) function in J. I wanted to do this by using `~` with a hook, like `f =: ((> & 2) #)~` but it seems like neither that nor `((> & 2) #~)` works.

My reasoning was that my function has the form `(f y) g y` where `y` is the list, `f` is `(> & 2)`, and `g` is `#`. I would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Everything is OK except you mixed the order of the hook. It's `y f (g y)` so you want

```
 (#~ (>&2)) y
```

Comment: This pattern of a filter for copying is very common in J. The words that form in my mind when I see `#~` appear at the left of a hook are "copy where." In this case, "copy where greater than two."

Answer (score 1):

Hooks have the form `f g` and the interpretation, when applied to a single argument (i.e. monadically) is  `(unaltered input) f (g input)`.  So, as Eelvex noted, you'd phrase this as a hook like `hook =: #~ >&2` .  Also, as kaledic noted, the idiom `(#~ filter)` is extremely common in J, so much that it's usually read as a cohesive whole: keep-items-matching-filter.*

If you wanted a point-free phrasing of the operation which looks similar, notationally, to the original noun-phrase `(y > 2) # y` , you might like to use the fork `>&2 # ]` where `]` means "the unaltered input" (i.e. the identity function) or even `(] # 2:) # ]` or some variation.

(*)  In fact, the pattern `(f~ predicate)` defines an entire class of idioms, like `(<;.1~ frets)` for cutting an array into partitions and `(</.~ categories)` for classifying the items of an array into buckets.